# In Trino (Presto) SQL, how do you convert a varchar (string) to an array of characters (char)?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I want to create a array of characters from a varchar field. For example, from `'test'`, I want to have `ARRAY['t', 'e', 's', 't']`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('test', '.') AS letters;`

returns:

| # | letters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["t","e","s","t",""] |